# Is it possible to configure properties like jcr:PrimaryType from a maven install

Tags: maven, aem

I'm following the steps from the Adobe instructions on [How to Build AEM Projects using Maven](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html) and I'm not seeing how to populate or configure the meta data for the contents.

I can edit and configure the actual files, but when I push the zip file to the CQ instance, the installed component has a jcr:primaryType of nt:folder and the item I'm trying to duplicate has a jcr:primaryType of cq:Component (as well as many other properties).  So is there a way to populate that data without needing to manual interact with CQ?

I'm **very** new to AEM, so it's entirely possible I've overlooked something very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible to configure JCR node types without manually changing with CQ.

Make sure you have **.content.xml** file in component folder and it contains correct **jcr:primaryType** ( e.g. jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"). 
This file contains metadata for mapping JCR node on File System.

For beginners it may be useful take a look [VLT](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-3/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html), that used for import/export JCR on File System. Actually component's files in your project should be similar to VLT component export result from JCR.

Comment: Exactly what I was needing!  Thanks!